# Typescript 2 Generic types dependent on each other

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have two types of config one for auth and one for general config which doesn't have any secret variables I used to have two functions but now I'm trying to have only one function but I wasn't able to implement this code with errors, I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong

```
interface config {
    config: string;
    config_example: string;
} 

interface auth {
    auth: string;
    auth_example: string;
}

type configType = "auth" | "config";
type getType<C extends configType> = C extends "auth" ? keyof auth : C extends "config" ? keyof config : never;

const auth: auth = {
    auth: '',
    auth_example: ''
}

const config: config = {
    config: '',
    config_example: ''
}

function getConfig<
    C extends configType,
    K extends keyof getType<C>
>(config: C, key: K): getType<C>[K] {
    switch (config) {
        case "auth":
            return auth[key];
        case "config":
            return config[key];
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}
```

here's the typescipt playground code of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQexDYBzZBvAKGWNQy2wC5kBnMKUbAbiJPUxwH0IAPOAWwAOAGwhVa9EEwIBfZAQKhIsRCjgBXMAAt8LYuq1i6DZiWT7NXXoJGGJU6fLABPASjbkAKi5QBeZACJzf2QAHwD3HH9mZ1dkbAgwL1cAHgBhZB5IEAATalJ2bCSIAD5kP3TMiBy8wI1NYIB+ZABrCCc0GDM65CoK7izc8LJI5CbW9s6I3CoQCAA3aGYCNlougzXtP0JTcyoAcj2AGl0Ny35hUWQDmXkVsHzyKimynVMp-aOTqbPrS+uHAgwNQgBBgYAYOIJVLDbDJE59AZ5KZFY6mADSGX6VUG4w6kMS3jSxQIxQAFO9kKlDi02lQ0QBKKjxAkpVLFADaaIAuq8SNQAO7AMAIbTkmH03mmYgIODUFC1LT+CgnKUkKAJNRQEAbdnjLkmVWoWXyqZKlWG9VgTXaqa6tr683EbIQeBqIRgZWGqVaKBofnIWb+gCiUF9UFJ9INxAcsiAA)

If I put //@ts-ignore to the errors, the IDE correctly determines the types and everything but I don't want to implement this with //@ts-ignore I don't even know if this is possible to do that but any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See [Wishlist: support for correlated union types #30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

```ts
const allConfigs = {
  "auth": auth,
  "config": config
}

function getConfig<
    CONFIG_NAME extends keyof typeof allConfigs,
    CONFIG_KEY extends keyof typeof allConfigs[CONFIG_NAME]
>(config: CONFIG_NAME, key: CONFIG_KEY): typeof allConfigs[CONFIG_NAME][CONFIG_KEY] {
    return allConfigs[config][key];
}
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQexDYBzZBvAKGWNQy2wC5kBnMKUbAbiJPUxwH0IAPOAWwAOAGwhVa9EEwIBfAgVCRYiFHACuYABb4WxNZrF0GzEsj0auvQSIMSpsgm1qn1GqmeQBebSbNUA5H4ANDrOmhb8wqLIATJyjmCk7JSJ5J7erGQ4-kEhbOThVlEx9vGmQkIAwpnY1GmEJgBEZg1uLsGNeTgtKTixBDCqIAhgwBjI2BBgVUkAPCEVAPIAcgBiAJIA4hxLAIIAsgCiyDyQIAAmtQDWEACeaDDIYDcCEPdlldXU7SSLq5scAGkDgBNY7cU4XZDXO4PJ4vN5wcrTcjUADav3WW12hwAugQAHwACk6yQx-2xB0CUNuVDJWyBwIAlFQ4a8HoiPkk0XTtvsDjj0ctMYCQTj0sQoJNVFAQO9kTg0SSBdCccxpMgCEA)

Comment: Uh... why the `switch`/`case` statement?  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NaEYyN) not work for some reason?

Comment: @jcalz Indeed - even in the unlikely case when someone passes unknown `config` name as `any`, TypeError "Cannot read properties of undefined" is thrown - no need to check it ourselves. I updated the answer.

Comment: ... did you?  I don't see it.

Comment: @jcalz Now I'm pretty sure the change is applied.